# Julia - array of boolean element-wise operation

Tags: julia

I do not understand the following element wise boolean operation result (see arrow on last part):

```
A = [1,2,3,1,2]
B = [1,2,1,3,2]

julia> A.==1
5-element BitArray{1}:
  true
 false
 false
  true
 false

julia> B.==1
5-element BitArray{1}:
  true
 false
  true
 false
 false

julia> A.==1 .& B.==1
5-element BitArray{1}:
  true
 false
 false
  true        <----- I expect this to be false
 false
```

The 4th element of A.==1 .& B.==1 should be false because it is (true & false).
Can someone explain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Operator precedence issue.

You have (by omission):

```
(A .== (1 .& B) .==1)
```

You need:

```
(A .== 1) .& (B .==1)
```

[Relevant docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/index.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity-1). Note that `&` (defined as multiplication) comes before `==` (defined as comparison).